# Migration(or conversion) path map in R

Tags: r, path, visualization

I need to make migration(or conversion) path map in R.

There is the example of my data.frame

```
ID order state
1      1     a
1      2     b
1      3     b
2      1     b
2      2     b
2      3     c
3      1     b
3      2     c
4      1     a
4      2     b
5      1     c
```

In this data.frame ID1 have moved to a -> b -> b according to the order.

In the same perspective, ID2 have moved to b -> b -> c, ID3 have moved to b-> c, ID4 have moved to a->b. And ID5 did not move.

In the aggregate level, we can make migration (or conversion) path map like below.

In this map, the arrows have frequency information of path. And the circles have frequency information of states.

[image: migration]

How can I make this path map in R? Is there any packages for this?

Comment: It's considered off-topic to ask us to find packages/libraries for you. Please edit to make this question more focused on a programming task or consider posting elsewhere.

Comment: I would suggest you try implementing this with `igraph` and then come back if you run into a specific programming issue. Make sure to include the code you've tried in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possibility using the `diagram` package. Most of the work here is just reshaping the data into a nice format. There may be more efficient ways, but this at least seems to work. First, your data. I also want to make sure that we treat the `order` column as a factor rather than a numeric value.

```
#sample input data
dd<-structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L), order = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
    state = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), 
    .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor")),
    .Names = c("ID", "order", "state"), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
dd$order<-factor(dd$order)
```

Now we begin the transformation. We need to create an adjaceny matrix between all the state/order positions

```
ss <- interaction(dd$state, dd$order)
Embed <- function(x) if(length(x)>1) embed(x,2) else numeric(0)
adj <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(as.numeric(ss), dd$ID), Embed))
tf <- function(x) factor(levels(ss)[x], levels=levels(ss))
tt <- table(tf(adj[,1]), tf(adj[,2]))
```

Then we re-name the rows of the matrix (because that's what is used as labels on the plot)

```
rownames(tt) <- paste(levels(dd$state), table(dd$state, dd$order), sep="/")
```

And now we focus on the layout. We assign positions to each circle, then plot the diagram with the transitions, and finally add the text at the top.

```
xpos<-cbind(rep(1:nlevels(dd$order), each=nlevels(dd$state)), 
   rev(rep(1:nlevels(dd$state), nlevels(dd$order))))
xpos<-(xpos-1)/2*.7+.15
plotmat(tt, pos=xpos)
text(paste("order", levels(dd$order)), x=unique(xpos[,1]), y=1, xpd=NA)
```

The final result is

[image]

I tried to make it as robust as possible to different numbers of states/orders but I didn't fully test it. So be sure to double check the results with your real data.

Comment: It is good! Thank you for your help.
Especially, the points of this approach is greatly helpful to me.